# Why cannot @DiscriminatorValue JPA annotation be used with abstract class?

Tags: java, jpa

Why cannot `@DiscriminatorValue` *JPA annotation*  be used with *abstract class*?

When some (concrete) child class is instantiated, its (abstract) parent class anyway *is also created and exists somewhere in memory*, because, say - child's constructor calls abstract parent's constructor passing it some values to be used by abstract parent's constructor for setting its (abstract parent's) fields.

Comment: Because it determines which value is used to determine what class is being instantiated when read from the database. Putting that on an abstract class doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@DiscriminatorValue` is used to determine which class needs to be instantiated. Abstract classes however can't be instantiated, so `@Discriminatorvalue` makes no sense above a abstract class.

Abstract classes can only be extended by concrete classes, or can be used to create a anonymous class.

Comment: Idea to look from "read (class name) from Database -> decide which class to instantiate - was very helpful. Before I always started thinking about class first and how it will be saved to db later.